# How can I do string interpolation in a string variable in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable coming from a static JSON file:

```
`const label = json.myString`
```

Where json.myString is `"Hello, ${ name }"`. Since this is a variable, I do not know what it would be before hand.

And I want to do some string interpolation in my react component:

```
<div>{ label }</div>
```

How can I do this? Bonus points for a backup/default option if `xyz` is undefined

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here ?

Comment: Updated to make it clearer

Comment: What are you matching those variables inside with ... like `name` must be matched to a variable `name` in your context. Where is that coming from?

Comment: It's being passed down to the component. For example, it's what the user input in another text field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use template engine for this, for example, [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

---

However, you can use an `eval`, but you don't want to use it, because it is unsafe in your case (some injections can be performed, if someone will perform a MITM-attack for your server, for example).

```js
var a = "kappa"
console.log(eval("`Hello, ${a}!`"))
```

---

The other option that you can use is *regular expressions*. 
There are 2 moments, that you should notice in this case:

1. Variables must be exist in some context, e.g. `this`, to allow stringified variables names be passed as key
2. You should not use special symbols of your template bounds inside template, or you should additionaly handle each special symbol inside regular expression.

```js
var template = "My awesome template says: \"${ say }\""
var data = { say: "Hello!" }

console.log(template.replace(/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g, (match, group) => {
  return data[group.trim()]
}))
```

---

By the way, this question is not React-specific, I suppose, but JS-specific. React doen't provide any profit features for this kind of logic tasks :)

Comment: I'm using react, so I don't want to use Mustache

Comment: @mergesort I have updated my answer and provided one more quick workaround

Comment: using eval may need to pass a purify functionality. For example, using DOMPurify, the usage can be: 

`var content = eval("\`"+DOMPurify.sanitize(result)+"\`")`

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of template literals is to avoid the usage of `"some string" + "another string"`, and not much functionally.

In this scenario, it would be best to decouple the `name` with `Hello`. 
That way, you could call

`<div>Hello, ${name} </div>`

In case you'd like to create a flexible greeting as well, you could then add the greeting as another string. E.g.:

`{ 
  name: "John Doe",
  greeting: "Hello"
}`

And go,
`<div>${greeting}, ${name}</div>`